pivot view sort on custom field not working
I have created:

a new Integer-field in the model: "crossovered.budget.lines", so that its _order can is customizable
I have used this field in ir.filter to customize the order of records in VIEWS

Both work properly with tree views.
But none of them work for pivot view.
Do you have an idea how to deal with it ?
class CrossoveredBudgetLines(models.Model):
    _inherit = "crossovered.budget.lines"
    _order = "isort desc, name"

    # store = True to enable its use with search, groupby, pivot, etc.
    name = fields.Char(compute='_compute_line_name', store=True)
    isort = fields.Integer(string='mon ordre', default=0)


